# Error when changing subreport recordsource: "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a form with a subreport on it, which occasionally references / changes the recordsource of said report. This has been working perfectly for *months*. I recently went back and started tweaking a few things in it, namely the tab order. I added in some code that checks which button was used to open it and changes the tab order based on that. As soon as I started testing if this was working or not, the Error

> "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the
>   property Form/Report"

started appearing on every line that references the report recordsource. I've tried removing the code I added before the error appeared but that didn't cause the error to go away.

Example of code that gets the error:

```
Me.rRAM10x10.Report.RecordSource = "tRAM10x10"
```

Code that I added right before the error started:

```
If CurrentProject.AllForms("fHighRisk").IsLoaded = True Then
    If Screen.ActiveControl.Name = "btnRAMimpact" Then
        Me.btnForFocus.TabIndex = 0
    ElseIf Screen.ActiveControl.Name = "btnRAMlhood" Then
        Me.Tabordertest.TabIndex = 0
    End If
End If
```

I did some research and found that this can be caused by the parent form not having any records, but that is not the case here. Other than what I posted above, no changes have been made to this form, the report, or any of the tables I'm setting its recordsource to since I finished changing it *months* ago.

The OnOpen Event of the Form:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim sID As Integer

If CurrentProject.AllForms("fRiskAssessmentTest").IsLoaded = True Then
    sID = Forms!fRiskAssessmentTest!fHighRisk!ScenarioID.Value
ElseIf CurrentProject.AllForms("fHighRisk").IsLoaded = True Then
    sID = Forms!fHighRisk!ScenarioID.Value
Else
    sID = 1
End If

Me.lblScenarioID.Caption = "Scenario " & sID

If CurrentProject.AllForms("fHighRisk").IsLoaded = True Then
    If Screen.ActiveControl.Name = "btnRAMimpact" Then
        Me.btnForFocus.TabIndex = 0
    ElseIf Screen.ActiveControl.Name = "btnRAMlhood" Then
        Me.Tabordertest.TabIndex = 0
    End If
End If

clr1 = RGB(122, 197, 205)
clr2 = RGB(152, 245, 255)

'button colors
Dim lblName As String, btnName As String, lblCaption As String, Rating As                 
Integer, ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If ctrl.ControlType = acCommandButton Then
        ctrlName = ctrl.Name
        Me.Controls(ctrlName).BackColor = clr2
    End If
Next

'Darkens buttons if value is stored in table
For i = 1 To 5
    lblName = "Vardisp" & i
    lblCaption = Me.Controls(lblName).Caption
    If IsNull(DLookup("[Variable Impact]", "tImpact", "scenarioID = " & sID &     
" AND [Impact Variable] = """ & lblCaption & """ ")) Then
        GoTo Skip_loop2
    Else
        Rating = DLookup("[Variable Impact]", "tImpact", "scenarioID = " & 
sID & " AND [Impact Variable] = """ & lblCaption & """ ")
    End If

    For b = 1 To 10
        If Rating = b Then
            btnName = "Var" & i & "R" & b
            Me.Controls(btnName).BackColor = clr1
        End If
    Next

Skip_loop2:
Next

End Sub
```

I'm pretty lost on what's causing this, so any help is greatly appreciated. Everything I've been able to find relating to it is caused by the parent forms recordset not having any records, and since that's not the case here, I'm struggling to find a direction to head with it.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you set the recordsource manually from the Properties details?

Comment: So I commented out all the lines that cause the error to test setting the recordsource manually, and the entire form is blank for some reason. None of the other controls show up (buttons, labels, textboxes). I've made sure they're all set to visible and to comment out anything that would change that, and the form is still blank. I changed the recordsource of the subreport manually and it caused no change; the form was still blank.

Comment: Then there's a problem with your recordsource. Open it up and look at it

Comment: There's nothing wrong with them as far as I can tell, they're just tables with some data in them, which hasn't changed. Also, why would the recordset of a subreport in a form affect the visibility of the other controls in that form?

Comment: You don't show your code that opens the form - are you using a filter? You don't show code in your Form Open event

Comment: I added the Open event to my post. All it's doing is labeling and coloring controls. There were calls to other subs in there, which is where the errors were occuring (see the example of the lines getting the error in my post), but I removed them during troubleshooting prior to posting and nothing changed. I have not put these calls back in since removing them.

Comment: Sure that you have a sub**REPORT** on a form?

Comment: Yes, I can say with 100% certainty that it is a report, considering the problem code is `Me.rRAM10x10.REPORT.RecordSource = "tRAM10x10"` and has been working for months up until now.

Comment: If the form is blank - you need to check the form's recordsource property - not the subreport's recorfsource. You should add option explicit to the top of the form's module and compile it to pickup any obvious errors

Comment: The form's recordsource doesn't effect anything because the form doesn't use any records. It's just holding controls that aren't tied to the recordsource, if that makes sense, I'm not sure how to properly word what I want to say. Regardless, I changed the parent forms recordsource a few times just to make sure, and nothing changed. I added Option Explicit to the module, it yelled at me about not declaring the variables in my `For` loops, and then went back to giving an error on the `Me.rRAM10x10.Report.RecordSource = "tRAM10x10"` lines.

Comment: Is `rRAM10x10` the name of subform/subreport container control as well as the report object? Recommend you name container different from the object it holds, such as ctrRAM then use that name in the code. You don't post procedure that sets the RecordSource.

Comment: The procedure that sets the RecordSource is just a Case statement based on user input. I built it a long time ago when I was first learning VBA, and as a result is very long. All it does is change Top/Caption/Visibility properties of controls, as well as the RecordSource of the report in question. The example of code that gets the error references a different table depending on user input, which is also placed in the Case statement. If you still want me to post that section of code, I will, but the point of the example code was to save people having to read it all, since it was irrelevant.